# Scrape multiple accounts aka multiple logins

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I can successfully scrape data for a single account. I want to scrape multiple accounts on a single website, which means multiple logins. How do I manage login/logout?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can scrape multiples accounts in parallel using multiple cookiejars per account session,
see "cookiejar" request meta key at [http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html?highlight=cookiejar#std:reqmeta-cookiejar](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html?highlight=cookiejar#std%3areqmeta-cookiejar)

To clarify: 
suppose we have an array of accounts in `settings.py`:

```
MY_ACCOUNTS = [
    {'login': 'my_login_1', 'pwd': 'my_pwd_1'},
    {'login': 'my_login_2', 'pwd': 'my_pwd_2'},
]
```

And this is the link to the login page: `http://example.com/login`

Create `start_requests`function in your spider, in this function we can loop on the `MY_ACCOUNTS` array and login to each account:

```
def start_requests(self):
    requests = []

    for i, account in enumerate(self.crawler.settings['MY_ACCOUNTS']):
        request = FormRequest('http://example.com/login', 
            formdata={'form_login_name': account['login'], 'form_pwd_name': account['pwd']}, 
            callback=self.parse,
            dont_filter=True)

        request.meta['cookiejar'] = i
        requests.append(request)

    return requests
```

`form_login_name` and `form_pwd_name` are respectively fields names on the login form.

`dont_filter=True` For ignoring filter on duplicate requests, because here we make a POST request to login on the same page `http://example.com/login`

`request.meta['cookiejar'] = i` to separate cookies of each session(login), dont forget to add `cookiejar` identifier in your sub request, suppose you want to redirect scrapy to a page after login:

```
def parse(self, response): 
    """ make some manipulation here ... """

    yield Request(my_url, meta={'cookiejar': response.meta['cookiejar']}, callback = my_callback)
```

Comment: Is there a way to limit the number of concurrent connection per cookiejar ? Similar to the setting CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN but per session context ?