# How to use Scrapy to handle complex login

Tags: authentication, scrapy

I am trying to crawl data from a website where I need to login first. I want to simulate the login using scrapy, but the login process for this website is a little bit complex.

First I need to get the servertime, rsa keys, blahblah from the server. Then assemble my post data, and make another request. At last, get login redirection url from previous response, request this url to login and save cookie.

I checked the [document](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#using-formrequest-from-response-to-simulate-a-user-login) of scrapy which tells me to use `FormRequest`, fill the from with username and password and login. But how to use scrapy to handle login process I mention above.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23827978/scrap-multiple-accounts-aka-multiple-logins/23832033#23832033

Comment: @LhassanBaazzi Thank you. But the problem here is I can't simply use `FormRequest` to login.